# Eventos periódicos con fecha del mes

Tags: php

Intento crear una función en php que me devuelva un array de fechas. Y todo esto del primer jueves del mes por cada dos meses, para ello envío un rango de fechas como el 2017/07/10 al 2017/12/31. Es una función que estuve intentando crear no pude conseguir la lista de fechas. Espero me apoyen con este tema. Con respecto a los días esto puede variar. Puede ser el primer jueves, lunes, martes, viernes del mes y puede ser por cada dos o tres meses dependiendo del usuario. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

function fechasArray($fechaInicio, $fechaFin, $diasaTomar = array()) {
    $arrayFechas = array();
    $fechaInicio = new DateTime($fechaInicio);
    $fechaFin = new DateTime($fechaFin);
    foreach ($diasaTomar as $diaaTomar) {
        $fechaReferencia = clone $fechaInicio;
        while ($fechaReferencia->format('w') != $diaaTomar) {
            $fechaReferencia->modify('+1 day');
        }
        while($fechaReferencia <= $fechaFin) {
            if ($fechaReferencia->format('w') == $diaaTomar) {
                $arrayFechas[$fechaReferencia->format('l')][] = $fechaReferencia->format('Y-m-d');
            }
            $fechaReferencia->modify('+ 2 months');
        }
        unset($fechaReferencia);
    }
    return $arrayFechas;
}

$diasaTomar = array(4); //dia jueves
$fechas=fechasArray('2017-07-09', '2017-12-31', $diasaTomar);

print_r($fechas);

Mi problema es que no puedo obtener el primer jueves del mes.

Comment: Y qué has intentado @Valeria? Se trata de ayudarte con los problemas de código. Añade lo que hayas probado y dónde tienes problemas para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Espero te sirva esta funcion que obtiene los primeros jueves de cada mes, de un año determinado.

```
function obtener_jueves($fecha1){
// inicio obtener primer jueves de cada mes
$arrayprimermes = array();
$arrayjuevesano = array();
$primerdiaano   = substr($fecha1,0,4);

$dt = new DateTime($primerdiaano . '-01-01');
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
    array_push($arrayprimermes, $dt->format('Y-m-d'));

    //buscar jueves
    $dt_busjue = new DateTime( $dt->format('Y-m-d') );
    $bandenc = false;
    for ($s=0; $s<= 6; $s++){
       if($bandenc == true) continue ;
       if($dt_busjue->format('w') == '4' ){
          echo $dt_busjue->format('Y-m-d') . " ** Primer jueves del mes ". $dt_busjue->format('m') ."<br>";
          array_push( $arrayjuevesano, 
                      $dt_busjue->format('Y-m-d'));
          $bandenc = true;
        }
        $dt_busjue->modify("+1 day");
    }

    $dt->modify("+1 month");    
}

//print_r($arrayprimermes);
echo "<br>";
print_r($arrayjuevesano);
}

$fecha1 = '2017-07-01' ;
obtener_jueves($fecha1);
```